# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0

Tags: java

I am trying to replace all square brackets i my string .

This is my program

```
   package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class Teste {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws JSONException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {


        String str = "[Fountain#Apple#Big(7)]";

        str.replaceAll("[", "").replace("]", "");

        System.out.println(str);

    }

}
```

But i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0
[
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.Teste.main(Teste.java:19)
```

Could anybody please tell me how to replace all square brackets ??

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`String.replaceAll` takes a regular expression pattern, but you don't need regular expressions at all. You can use:

```
str = str.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Or you *could* use a regex if you wanted, replacing both in one go:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
```

That's saying "replace any character in the set (open square bracket, close square bracket) with the empty string. The `\\` is to escape the square brackets within the set.

Note that you need to use the result of `replace` (or `replaceAll`) - strings are immutable in Java, so any methods like `replace` don't modify the *existing* string, they return a reference to a *new* string with the relevant modifications.